# Disable image writing support in libPNG

Tags: png, libpng

I'm trying to reduce the size of libPNG by disabling image writing support, since the software I'm writing does not require it. I thought that commenting out "option WRITE" in scripts/pnglibconf.dfa would achieve this, but it still builds in pngwrite.c and the size of the resulting library file is the same as when "option WRITE" is not commented. Is there something else I need to do in order to disable image writing support in libPNG? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well it appears there are two "option WRITE"s in pnglibconf.dfa and you have to comment both of them out to disable writing support. However, I'm now getting lots of missing options in the dependency tree so it won't build. I tried going through and commenting out all of the things which depended on write support, but some of them aren't listed as options so there's nothing to comment. For example, "option pHYs" depends on "WRITE_pHYs", but "option pHYs" is not defined anywhere in pnglibconf.dfa.

Comment: Remove "chunk pHYs" to disable pHYs chunk support.  As explained in comments in scripts/options.awk, "chunk" is a macro that expands to the appropriate "option" settings.

Comment: I've removed the confusing redundant "option WRITE" from the libpng GIT repositories at SourceForge and Github/glennrp/libpng.  This change will eventually appear ln libng-1.6.21.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contrib/pngminim/decoder directory in the libpng distribution includes an example pngusr.dfa to do what you want.  It turns all options off and then turns on just the ones that are needed for sequential reading.

Comment: Thanks Glenn! I did try with the pngminim/decoder configuration last night, but I did so by copying the files contained in this directory into the root of the libpng source bundle. I managed to build it today by entering this directory and making from there, which worked and it produced a nice small (61448 byte) Linux binary. I actually need to cross-compile as an ARM static library be built into a Nintendo 3DS binary. Do you know if I can modify the makefile in the pngminim decoder to achieve this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is wandering off-topic, and there's more to it than will fit in this little text box, but you could have a look at how that's done in FIrefox Nightly for hints on how to proceed.

Comment: Thanks Glenn. I will look into that. I've accepted this as the correct answer as it clearly works, I just need t figure out how to cross compile it. Thanks again!